# Excel does not save changes to addins anymore after recent update to version 2108 build 14326.20738

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm using and maintaining some simple Microsoft Excel addins at work, and recently got updated to Excel 356 Enterprise version 2108 build 14326.20738, from version 2102.

Today, I wanted to make a small adjustment to one of the addins and found that the change did not get saved. I tried this with several addins to check if this is any file-specific effect, but so far it happened with all of them.

Changing the addin file with the Custom UI Editor tool is still possible, and the change done to the ribbon UI is also working.

But any changes to the addin VBA code done from within Excel itself via the VBA editor do not get saved and are gone when Excel is closed and reopened.

I can't find any recent instances of this problem in web searches - is this a known issue with this Excel version, or could it be something in our work environment? What would I possibly be looking for there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible fix, though I am not sure why or what exactly this is fixing:

- In the properties of the ThisWorkbook object in the VBA Editor, the option IsAddin is set to True - expected, because it is an addin after all.
- To check if anything in that workbook was wrong, I set this to False, which opens the workbook in Excel.
- Everything seemed fine, so I changed this back to True.

Ever since I done this, saving changes in the VBA editor works again. The Save button displays the usual progress circle, this did not happen before.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to fix this problem:
Close all files in excel but excel should still be running.
Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> in order to go to the vba editor.
Then you can edit your code.